# Deploying web service from the Windows Azure toolkit for Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, azure, azure-storage

For a few days now I have been playing around with the Windows Azure toolkit for Windows Phone 7. I have recently been trying to deploy my web services to windows azure. I am having a problem with getting the certificate to work properly.

I have followed this walk through(minus the Apple Push Notification part) without any luck.
http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/05/deploying-your-services-from-the-windows-azure-toolkit-for-windows-phone-7/

Everything deployed to the cloud fine but when I tested it on the phone, I pressed the "install certificate" button and I always get an error saying the page cannot be found etc.

Any reason why this is doing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with this, I tried to package my service and deploy it directly to Windows Azure rather that using the Visual Studio Publish tool and it seems to be working.